# git - include other project

Tags: git, directory, workflow

Say I have a project `A` that makes use of another project `B`.

To that end, there's a subfolder in the git repository of `A` into which `B` has been cloned.

Now, the simplest way to sync that folder to `A's` repo would probably be to just add that folder and everything in it to `A's` index and be done with it.

As I have no experience with such nested git structures, I do wonder if that's a smart thing to do, though. Do I risk anything by doing it that way and what are the alternatives?

Comment: you have 2 options submodules  and subtree merging. I would recommend: subtree merging because it's easier to maintain. You just need to create each repository in the normal way. While in your "collector" repository, you may merge another repository in a directory of your "collector" directory. If you want to to put the commands let me know I will add an answer.

Comment: It's arguable if a subtree is easier to maintain than submodules. As a rule of thumb, if repository `B` changes often, it should be used as a subtree. If it sits on a relative stable stage, it should be used as submodule. A good article on when to use submodules can be found [here](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-submodules-34c65e940407#.lhi1isank), the respective article on subtrees is [here](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-subtrees-943d29a798ec#.d5zzxh5kv).

Comment: @Teocci do feel free to elaborate into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to recommend: [subtree merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging) because it's easier to maintain, as @kowsky mentioned, when your project changes often.

You just need to create each repository in the normal way. While in your "collector" repository, you may merge another repository as a sub-directory of your "collector" directory. To do that just run these commands:

```
$ git remote add -f AnotherRepo /path/to/that/repo
$ git merge -s ours --no-commit AnotherRepo/master
$ git read-tree --prefix=AnyDirectoryToPutItIn/ -u AnotherRepo/master
$ git commit -m "Merge AnotherRepo project as subdirectory"`
```

Then, to pull the `AnotherRepo` into your "collector" repository (or to update it), use the sub-tree merge strategy:

```
$ git pull -s subtree AnotherRepo master
```

This is the common way to do it and it works :-)

More about this way including comparing it with sub modules may be found in this git [Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging)